# Hide and show list element HTML and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a page that would only show in the header tab when the user logs in. However, it should be hidden if the user isn't logged in.  How do I hide the element?

Here is my HTML:

```
<li ng-if="isAuthenticated" ><a active-link="active" href="#/dashboard"><span translate>Dashboard</span></a></li>
<li id="about"><a active-link="active" href="#/about"><span translate>About</a></li>
<li id="info"><a active-link="active" href="#/info"><span translate>Information</a></li>
```

When I used `$("#info").hide()` nothing happens. Any clue why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoqm8w70/

Comment: how do we know if user is authenticated.... looks like angularjs code... who is setting `isAuthenticated`

Comment: just load the jquery.. http://jsfiddle.net/dmxvjh7q/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't included jQuery in your JSFiddle demo. If you look at your JavaScript console you'll see the following error being displayed:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `$` is not defined

To fix it, select jQuery as an external resource from the dropdown list on the side:

[image: Example]

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hoqm8w70/1/).

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I've rolled back your edit. I can see your logic, but the Uncaught ReferenceError message isn't code, it's a quote from the JavaScript console.

Comment: James, you have more reputation than me, but your answer should have been a comment, right? That's why I gave you a downvote. Then I thought, ... , I removed my downvote, but it was locked. So I had to edit it to remove my downvote. Cheers.

Comment: Please do not encourage questions like this!

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's a perfectly valid question in my opinion. I couldn't find any suitable alternatives to warrant a duplicate flag, otherwise I'd have voted to close it instead.

Comment: You could have commented on it to just include that single script, right?

Answer (score 1):

you did not load jquery in your demo please see the fork:

```
$(function(){
    $("#info").hide();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1565f4xL/

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery loaded on your fiddle. With jQuery being loaded it works.

See this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cewqpjhm/

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
   $('#info').hide();
});
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I edited the code. You are right it should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="ul-container">    
<li ng-if="isAuthenticated" ><a active-link="active" href="#/dashboard"><span translate>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li id="about"><a active-link="active" href="#/about"><span translate>About</a></li>
    <li id="info"><a active-link="active" href="#/info"><span translate>Information</a></li>
</ul>

we can use : 
$('.ul-container').hide(); or $('.ul-container').css('display', 'none');
we can have :
.hide {
   display:none;
}
js : $('.ul-container').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some error on browser ReferenceError: $ is not defined
please choose js Frameworks & Extensions (jQuery framework)